# Image shows up in browser but cannot be downloaded with code (node.js)

Tags: node.js, image-processing, download, request, fetch

I have a client who has asked me to create thumbnails of images downloaded. I have a snippet of code which uses `node-fetch` to download the image into a buffer:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const URL =
  'https://lf.lids.com/hwl?set=sku[20905595],c[2],w[400],h[300]&call=url[file:product]';
async function main() {
  const t = await fetch(URL);
  const tt = await t.buffer();
  debugger;
}

main();
```

This works for most images except the one one in the code. I have a feeling lids.com may either be doing some redirect magic or preventing scraping from happening, but I'm not able to debug this.

I've also tried setting an assortment of headers to mimic the browser (which loads the image), but nothing has worked so far. I'm not sure if this is a library issue or an operational issue.

Comment: I'm running this in node.js on an AWS lambda so it shouldn't be a CORS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there are two issues:

- `Agent` needs to be changed to reflect the browser
- Some servers just straight up block anything from AWS to prevent scraping, we ended up using crawlera to get around this